ISchedulerConfiguration Cron hour doesn't work
I currently have a C# worker console project to which I have to assign to several threads the facility to run at specific times. With IScheduledEventConfiguration and the Cron() method I have used the expression * 13 * * * which according to crontab.guru should run my process every 1 minute as long as it is 13 hours of the day, but it does not run at all; but if I put * * * * * it works perfectly every minute.
this my code in Program.cs
 host.Services.UseScheduler(
     scheduler =>
foreach (var worker in workers)
{
    if (!(worker.Enabled ?? false)) continue;
    scheduler.OnWorker(worker.Name);
    IScheduleInterval schedulerSyncService;

    switch (worker.Profile!.ParseMode)
    {
        default:
            SyncEmpWorker.AddIsActive(worker.Name!);
            schedulerSyncService = scheduler.ScheduleWithParams<SyncEmpWorker>(worker);
            break;
    }

    var schedule = ScheduleManager.ScheduleFormat(worker.Schedule ?? string.Empty);
    var _schedulerSyncService =
        schedulerSyncService.Cron(schedule);
    if (worker.RunOnceAtStart ?? false)
        _schedulerSyncService.RunOnceAtStart();
}

I have tried using several expressions and looking for other methods including installing several nugets to solve the problem, but the time still does not work.

you have an extra asterisk.  * 13 * * *

Sorry, was my tipyng i add extra asterik. fixed it

if you are running the code in the cloud, the server time might be 13h for you but not on the server.

Nop, it running in local with Worker Console
